# Have to find a count of rows from my postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

Hi I tried to get a count of rows from my below query:

```
        select count(substring(wsresult_question FROM '[0-9]+') as pumporder) AS totals,
            job_id,
            job_siteid,
            job_completed
            from webserviceresults w, jobs s 
            where job_siteid = '1401' 
            and job_id = wsresult_jobid
            and job_completed is not null
            and wsresult_question LIKE 'job.job_site_data.site_meters.pump.%' 
            and wsresult_category = 'Job' 
            group by pumporder,job_id,job_siteid,job_completed order by job_completed desc
```

I tried this and i got the error like

```
There was an SQL error: 
ERROR: syntax error at or near "as" LINE 1: ... count(substring(wsresult_question FROM '[0-9]+') as pumpord... ^
```

In this line `substring(wsresult_question FROM '[0-9]+') as pumporder` I just tired to get only a number from some concatenate strings. The concatenate string  is being like

> 1.job.job_site_data.site_meters.pump.0.meter_calibration_record.meter_adjustedtofast
>
> 2.job.job_site_data.site_meters.pump.0.meter_calibration_record.meter_adjustedtoslow
>
> 3.job.job_site_data.site_meters.pump.1.meter_calibration_record.meter_adjustedtofast

So `substring(wsresult_question FROM '[0-9]+') as pumporder` is return the numbers like 0,1 in array. I need to total the count of rows now. So Kindly help me on this.

Please let me know if you have any queries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error means you should not create an alias for the function - only for the column, so if you remove `as pumporder` from `count(substring(wsresult_question FROM '[0-9]+') as pumporder)` , error will go away

Your approach though is very doubtful. If you want to count number of rows with `substring(wsresult_question FROM '[0-9]+')`, you better instead:

```
    select count(1) AS totals,
        job_id,
        job_siteid,
        job_completed
        from webserviceresults w, jobs s 
        where job_siteid = '1401' 
        and job_id = wsresult_jobid
        and job_completed is not null
        and wsresult_question  ~ '^(job.job_site_data.site_meters.pump.)[0-9]' 
        and wsresult_category = 'Job' 
        group by pumporder,job_id,job_siteid,job_completed order by job_completed desc
```

and lastly the string `job.job_site_data.site_meters.pump.0` looks like json path, so it would be more appropriate using json array length function, not count on rows